# d3.js Multi-line graph with zoom : line error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It is my version of "Multi-line graph 4: Toggle" from http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e99a762017060ce81c76 but I ran into some problems pls help.

At first the initial graph is correct,

- after the zooms, the line would become one which used data for both line and rotated.

I think it is the zoomed functions is not doing right, when I used "d.value" the browser would say "d. is not define"

Here are the codes:

```js
// https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10
var colors = d3.scale.category10(); 

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 85},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 570 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Kind of defining the length and the directions of the axis    
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]); 

// Since the origin is on the left corner, the y axis of the svg system points down 
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]); 
    
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height) 
    .tickPadding(10)   // Distance between axis and tick note 
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0"))    
    .orient("bottom");  
    
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".3e")) // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format  
    .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.samples); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.measurements); });

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 50])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

// Adding svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
data=[{"SAMPLES":"1","MEASUREMENTS":"2","ID":"ch1"},{"SAMPLES":"2","MEASUREMENTS":"3","ID":"ch1"},{"SAMPLES":"1","MEASUREMENTS":"4","ID":"ch2"},{"SAMPLES":"3","MEASUREMENTS":"5","ID":"ch1"},{"SAMPLES":"2","MEASUREMENTS":"6","ID":"ch2"}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.samples = +d.SAMPLES;
    d.measurements = +d.MEASUREMENTS;
});

console.log(data);

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.samples; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.measurements; })]);

// Creating X axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
// Drawing notations
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
    .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("x", (width - margin.left)/2)
        .attr("y", height + margin.top + 45)
        .text('Samples'); 

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
 
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
        .attr("x", -height/2)
        .text('Volts');

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Nest the entries by channel id (ID)
var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.ID;})
    .entries(data);

// set the colour scale    
var color = d3.scale.category10();

// Auto spacing for the legend
legendSpace = width/dataNest.length;

// Loop through each IDs / key to draw the lines and the legend labels
dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) {
    
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.color = color(d.key); 
        })
        .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) // assign ID
        .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
        .style("stroke", function(){return d.color = color(d.key);});

    // Adding legends
    svg.append("text")

        // Setting coordinates and classes
        .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace) 
        .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
        .attr("class", "legend")

        // Setting colors
        .style("fill",function(){
            return d.color = color(d.key);
        })

        // Setting 'click' events
        .on("click", function(){
            
            // Determine if current line is visible
            var active = d.active ? false : true,
            newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            
            // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
            .transition().duration(600)
            .style("opacity", newOpacity);

            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            d.active = active;
        })

        .text(function() {
            if (d.key == '28-00043b6ef8ff') {return "Inlet";}
            if (d.key == '28-00043e9049ff') {return "Ambient";}
            if (d.key == '28-00043e8defff') {return "Outlet";}
            else {return d.key;}
        })
})

// Zoom specific updates

function zoomed() {
  
    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis")
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll('path.line')
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('d', valueline(data));
}
```

```css
body {
 font: 12px Arial;
 margin: 50px;
}

.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #bbb;
    stroke-width: 2;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    fill: #555;
}
 
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1;    
    stroke: #e7e7e7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.axis .axis-label {
    font-size: 14px;
}
 
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

Comment: note also that javascript is case sensitive. So in your data you have samples and measurements twice - once (capitalized) as strings and once with the converted type. I guess you just need the latter for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your paths to your data, so you can call `valueLine` with the correct data for the path when zooming.
Use d3 `data` and `enter` functions when adding a new path:

```
// choose all .line objects and append a path which is not already binded 
// by  comparing its data to the current key
svg.selectAll(".line").data([d], function (d) {
  return d.key;
})
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
```

Then when you zoom, change the `d` attribute path by calling `valueLine` with the path's correct values:

```
svg.selectAll('path.line')
    .transition().duration(500)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
     return valueline(d.values)
      });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUfnXjv89FGeCH98iiBj?p=preview)